# Where is Cyberlink DVD Suite and how can I remove it?

Tags: windows-xp, adware

I have a program installed named Cyberlink DVD Suite. When I invoke it a window comes up offering an ability to configure. In there I can return to "Power starter" (my only other clue. It is adware trying to get me to buy it. It is not in the Add/remove programs under either name.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyberlink DVD Suite is genuine software, but I personally just prefer to use VLC player.

I can only guess that it was a botched install/uninstall.

Look at the media that came with your computer and see if you can reinstall it, and hopefully then you can also uninstall it.

If you do not want to do this, go to `My Computer` and right click the `CD/DVD Drive`, next go to the `Autoplay` Tab, and you should be able to control default actions from there.

[image]

To then remove Cyberlink DVD Suite, take a look in its program folder and see if there is an uninstall utility, if there isn't, try to download a trial of the latest version then uninstall it, or if the guide above works, you may just want to leave it there. It installs a lot of codecs and system files and you do not want to just start deleting it.

(If however you do want to start deleting, you may want to take a look at [Microsoft / Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) which should allow you to see various drivers and codecs that are located in the Cyberlink folder and delete the system links before deleting the files.

Comment: Thank for such a complete seeming answer. I will try this. Regards,

Comment: @il: After re-reading your answer over the last while, I finally found it in the add/remove programs of the control panel under a name I did not anticipate. You get the accept. Thanks. Going to the "CD Drive>Properties" did not work. I could not change the default screen, no matter where I clicked. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

**This looks promising.**  **This is as qouted in**  [here](http://forum.cyberlink.com/forum/posts/list/8116.page;jsessionid=BBA69BD7081BD409212D7787510A0468)

> The only way I could get rid of it is
>   with **Revo Uninstaller**. Download it
>   from here
>   -- it's free. It's a tedious process and you have to remove individual
>   components with Revo Uninstaller
>   before you can remove the "suite"
>   component.